# how to free malloc outside of function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, malloc

Can't resolve this problem - my compiler allways tells me that I have some troubles with the free(pointer) function. So I'm not sure about the working of my pointers but debugging has shown that actually everything works well. Only the free function could't free the memory.

```
    #include <stdio.h>              //Bibliothek für input/output.
    #include <stdlib.h>             //For malloc
    #include <math.h>               //Bibliothek für matchematische Operationen.
    #include <iostream>             //Bibliothek für in/output in C++.
    #include <stdbool.h>            //Bibliothek für boolean

    //Prototypes
int* readNumbers(int size);
int sumUpNumbers(int* sumpointer, int size);

//Main function
int main()
{
    int arraySize;  //Size of the malloc-array
    int* pointer;   //pointer for storing of the malloc-address
    int total;      //variable for the sumUpNumbers function
    pointer = NULL; //point on zero

    //inform the user before getting a number from him
    std::cout << "Please give the size of array:" << std::endl;
    fflush(stdout); //free the output window
    //get a number for the size of array
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);

    //call the readNumbers function and store the first address of
    //the malloc-array in pointer
    pointer = readNumbers(arraySize);

    //call the sumUpNumbers function and store the number in total
    total = sumUpNumbers(pointer, arraySize);

    fflush(stdout); //free the output window
    //show the number from total
    printf("\n total of the array:%d", total);

    //call the free function for making the memory of
    //the malloc-array free again
    free(pointer);

    fflush(stdin);  //free the keyboard buffer
    getchar();      //wait for a feedback from user
    return 0;       //return 0 to the machine in case if everything works well
}


//This function has a pointer extension because we want to work with the
//array outside of this function. We give the function a size of the array
//we want to build. The function builds an array and fills it with numbers
//and than gives us back the first address of the array.
int* readNumbers(int size)
{

    int* array;         //pointer for creating of malloc-array
    int i;              //counter

    //pointer for storing of the first address of the array
    int* helpPointer;
    array = NULL;       //set the pointers
    helpPointer = NULL; //              on zero

    //create the array
    array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    //check the value of the array to be sure that we have created
    //the array without errors
    if(array != NULL)
    {
        //store the first address of the malloc-pointer
        helpPointer = array;
        //give some value to all the parts of array
        for(i=0; i<=size; i++)
        {
            //inform the user
            printf("\n give the %d. nummber of the array:\n", i+1);
            fflush(stdout); //free the output window
            //read the value
            scanf("%d", array+i);
        }

        return helpPointer; //return the first address
    }
    //if something went wrong by creating of the array, do:
    else
    {
        //tell the user, what we computer does't have enough memory
        std::cout << "There is no place for saving the data in mamory";
        return 0;   //return with failure
    }

}

//The input of this function is a pointer with the address of the malloc-array
//from the readNumbers and the size of this array. The function adds all the numbers
//from the array and gives us the result of the additation back.
int sumUpNumbers(int* sumpointer, int size)
{
    int sum;    //variable for storing of total value
    int i;      //counter
    sum = 0;    //set the sum on zero before work with it

    //count all the values from the array
    for(i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
        //count one number after another
        sum = sum + *(sumpointer+i);
    }
    return sum; //return the total value
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` Invokes undefined behavior and can cause the program to crash. Are you sure this isn't the actual problem? Just remove that line.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<=size; i++)` exceeds the memory allocated. Note: you don't have a "compiler error". Didn't you notice it is asking for one more entry than you told it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your compiler doesn't tell you that you have **some troubles**. Surely it is more specific than that. Also, why use malloc in c++?

Comment: And I'm fairly certain that it isn't the compiler at all, but a run-time exception from the OS...

Comment: Why use `malloc` and `free` with [tag:c++]. You have `new` and `delete `keywords...

Answer (score 2):

The limits of your `for` loops are wrong. You are writing into one position over the end of your array, which might corrupt the memory so that later the program fails. Change the `for` loops to:

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `readNumbers` function you have:

```
for(i=0; i<=size; i++)
```

but the array is only `size` elements long, so just change `<=` to `<`:

```
for(i=0; i < size; i++)
```

You have the same problem in the `sumUpNumbers` function. But this will most likely just result in an incorrect sum although it is technically undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has few issues:

1. `fflush(stdin)` is a generator of undefined behavior.
2. two incorrect counters: if size is `size`, you must count `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)`
3. Your `int* readNumbers(int size)` returns `int` instead of `int*` if `array` is `NULL`.
4. strange mixing of C and C++ for no obvious reason to using `cin` and `cout`

Apart from having written three obvious mistakes (1) and (2) and (3), you also push yourself to use a C++ compiler (4) for compiling something, 99% of which is plain C code. Why?

In case you replace `cin` and `cout` with appropriate `scanf()` and `printf()` calls, you get rid of C++. So you can use a C compiler. In that case make sure to also modify `malloc` call in order to conform the `C` standard:

```
array = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); //no result casting!
```

Then you get 100% C code which is easier to read, study and debug.

Comment: OP is compiling [tag:c++] code so `malloc` return value cast is mandatory.

Comment: I hope my answer is clear enough. I have advised OP for possibility of simplifying the code and making it 100% **plain C**, instead of having to use a C++ compiler for code which is **< 1% C++**, @LPs. For some reason it is tagged both C and C++ which is ambiguous. (-:

Comment: @user3078414 if you add issue 4 to your list it will be full I believe.
There is return 0 in readNumbers(). When changed to return NULL in C,
it will increase portability.